# How can I add two collection into collection android studio in firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a lesson add system using Firestore in android studio.

When the user adds a lesson, it will be added to Firestore and there will be a student and teacher collection in that lesson collection.

But I don't know how to do it.

If I write code for student and teacher collections, it adds two different collections, but I want to have 2 collections, both student and teacher, in one lesson collection.

How can I do this?

I share the code that I wrote.

**add lesson class**

```
private ActivityDersEkleBinding binding;
private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
private String txt_lesson;
private   LinkedHashMap<String,String> linkedHashMap;
private int i=1;
private CollectionReference Courses;

public void init(){
    linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Courses = mFirestore.collection("Courses");
    Ders_EKLE();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityDersEkleBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);
    init();
}

private void Ders_EKLE(){

    //Ders ekleme tam olmadı. Tekrar bakılacak.

    binding.btnEkleDers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            txt_lesson = binding.isimDers.getText().toString();

     //Show alertdialog if the user has entered an empty lesson 

            if(txt_ders.equals("")){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DersEkleActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("WARNING!");
                builder.setMessage("you cant empty value !");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warningicon);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
            else {

         //If a lesson has been entered, add it to the firestore.

                linkedHashMap.put("lesson"+i,txt_lesson); 


                int j=1;
                Courses.document("KDXnJKKno1D2xtG9G6UE").collection("Lessons")
                        .document()
                        .collection(txt_lesson)
                        .document()
                        .collection("Student")
                        .add(new DersEklePerson())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(@NonNull DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                Toast.makeText(DersEkleActivity.this,"Ders başarıyla eklendi.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });





            }

        }
    });

}
```

**EDIT**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore data model is:

1. At the top level you have collections.
2. In each collection you (can) have documents.
3. Each each document you can have nested collections again.
4. Etc.

So a collection can either exist at the root level, or under a **document**. You cannot have a collection directly inside a collection, as you repeatedly say you want in your question.

---

It is also most common to have symbolic names that you can specify in your code for collections such as `users`, `courses`, `lessons`, `questions`, etc. Then you can generate the IDs for the documents *inside* those collection.

You data model seems to not follow these common patterns, which I think is part of the reason you are running into problems.

---

Let's have a look at this code, with the knowledge above:

```
Courses.document("KDXnJKKno1D2xtG9G6UE").collection("Lessons")
        .document()
        .collection(txt_lesson)
        .document()
        .collection("Student")
        .add(new DersEklePerson())
```

- It starts good: `Courses` sounds like the name of a collection, and the document ID you have in there looks generated, so
- The `Lessons` subcollection also look good.
- But when you call `document()` like this, it generates a new document reference to a new, non-existing document, which seems unlikely to be what you want.
- More likely you want the lesson document that is identified by `txt_lesson`, which you'd do with `document(txt_lesson)`.
- If you do that, you also don't need the second `document()` call anymore.
- Then you have a `Student` subcollection, which looks good again.

  Well, I'd recommend calling it `Students`, since your other collection names are also plural.
- And then finally you call `add()` on that `Student` collection to generate a document for the student.

So after all of that, I think you need:

```
Courses.document("KDXnJKKno1D2xtG9G6UE").collection("Lessons")
        .document(txt_lesson)
        .collection("Student")
        .add(new DersEklePerson())
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it has become more simple and nice but I also want to have teacher collection under student collection.

Comment: I shared a picture above, you can see it there

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: Someting like `Courses.document("KDXnJKKno1D2xtG9G6UE").collection("Lessons").document(txt_lesson).collection("Teaches").add(...)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked :D